# How can I get a list of user names that use a facebook application?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have been searching for a way to get just the list of users from my facebook app. I've tried several FQL variations to no avail. I do NOT want the list of users that are my friends who are users of the app but an entire list of user names from my facebook app.

All the questions pertaining to this type of request get many answers but all of them focus on FRIENDS of a user who use the app.

I just need a list of IDs or names that are using my app and have authorized the app with extended permisions.

Any ideas?  I am using client-side javascript sdk.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no API for this. You should already have this information from your own logs though, assuming you're storing information about your app's users in a database somewhere

Comment: Thank you. I chose to write to text file since database is not an option in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Igy; that kind of statistical data is the responsibility of the developer.  Facebook provides other (very useful) statistics on usage and performance with their [insights feature](https://www.facebook.com/insights/), but to track individual users the developer will need to implement his or her own logs.